# Call my function from the google.maps.event.listener

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My component written in typescript for a page in my Ionic2 project has the follwing structure:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...
declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-search',
    templateUrl: 'search.html'
})

export class SearchPage {
    @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
    map: any;
    guideList: Array<Guide>;
    text: any;
    lat : any; 
    lon : any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public recoshService: Recosh, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit(){ 
        this.loadMap();
    }

    loadGuides() {
        ...
    }

    setLat(l){
        this.recoshService.setLat(l);
        this.lat = l;
    }

    setLon(l){
        this.recoshService.setLon(l);
        this.lon = l;
    }

    setPos(lat, lon){
        this.setLon(lon);
        this.setLat(lat);
        this.loadGuides();
    }

    loadMap(){
        ...

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: this.map.getCenter(),
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight:2,
                strokeColor:"#B40404"
            },
            draggable:true,
            map: this.map,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

            this.setPos(marker.getPosition().lat(),marker.getPosition().lng());

        });
    }
}
```

But Inside the `google.maps.event.addListener(){..}` I cant reach the `setPos()` declared inside my `SearchPage` class. How can I call this function considering my structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use arrow functions like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () => {
    this.setPos(marker.getPosition().lat(),marker.getPosition().lng());
});
```

By using arrow functions, the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance.